# Convert Docx to Doc using headless

Tags: python, libreoffice

I have run fallowing command on centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64 we get Command status: 0 doc file gernrated. But
centos-release-6-3.el6.centos.9.x86_64
Command:

```
libreoffice5.0 --headless --convert-to doc /temp/14628614434896/146286144349.docx --outdir /temp/14628614434896
```

Command status: 19712
I don't get any error and file also not generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.command : "sudo /etc/init.d/libreoffice start" this command start the libreoffice.

2.Use command to check libreoffice Port status: if it is not open Above command  is not generating desired output.
command: "netstat -ant | grep 8100"
status : "tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:8100   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN"
```

Now Run your command to Convert Docx to Doc using headless.